# Initiate objects from associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, initialization

I want to use the init() method to initiate objects taken from an associative array by a for..in loop:

```
var person = {name: null, id: null}

person.init = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "##" + this.name;
}

var pers1 = Object.create(person);
var pers2 = Object.create(person);

var personArray = {pers1: "John", pers2: "Alice"};

for (var i in personArray){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(personArray[i]);
    console.log(i.name);
    i.init(personArray[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
pers1
John       
undefined  // pers1.name
TypeError: i.init is not a function  //But not pers1.init() ?
```

Why can I call the .name attribute but not the .init() method?
And more importantly, is there a way to call the methods of objects in an array?

I am a beginner at JS so I'm sorry if the code looks a bit weird.

Comment: you use _Object_ not an associative array, so _for..in_ go for a properties and `i` is property name (_string_), and `personArray[i]` property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I call the .name attribute but not the .init() method?

In JavaScript, you can access non-existent properties on objects; when you do, you get back the value `undefined.` That's what you're doing: The values of the properties on `personArray` (which isn't an array) are strings, and don't have `name` or `init` properties. That's fine for accessing `.name`, because all you do is pass it to `console.log`, but you get an error for `.init` because you're trying to call `undefined` as a function.

The main issue is that your properties in the object (it's not an array) are not related in any way to your `person` function, and are not related in any way to your `pers1` and `pers2` objects.

If your goal is to start with an object with properties whose values are just names, and convert it into an object with objects *using* those names backed by the `person` object, you can do this:

```
var person = {name: null, id: null};

person.init = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "##" + this.name;
};

var personMap = {pers1: "John", pers2: "Alice"};

var name;
for (var i in personMap) {
    name = personMap[i];
    personMap[i] = Object.create(person);
    personMap[i].init(name);
}
```

Comment: Ooh haha how clumsy of me, Thanks for a great explanation and solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
var personArray = {pers1: "John", pers2: "Alice"};
```

this line is creating a new Object which only contains the keys `pers1` and `pers2` assigned to the strings `"John"` and `"Alice"`, you aren't assigning the objects you have created